# How to start google map from city instead whole worlld?

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I start google map from default city (i have it lat, lng and zoom). Now when I start my map, first of all I see whole world and after that map animated to my position.

Comment: don't use animate then!

Comment: but I don't want to see whole world.

Comment: what i mean that use simple zoom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Maps Android API allows you to change the user's viewpoint of the map by modifying the map's camera.

```
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GoogleMap `moveCamera(CameraUpdate update)` to avoid animation and go to direct your position
sample block is:-

```
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(19.111990, 72.834034)).title("Marker"));
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(19.111990, 72.834034))
            .zoom(15).build();
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this too:

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location location;
private Criteria criteria;

this.locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

criteria = new Criteria();

location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true));

                if (location != null) {
             // add marker on map at current location
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I am here"));

                // Creating a LatLng object for the current location

                // Showing the current location in Google Map
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                // to show current location on opening map
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
                }
```